# Prove That the Gram Matrix Determines Vectors Up to Isometry / Multiplication by Unitary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, isometry, positive-semidefinite, unitary-matrices

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramMatrix.html, the gram matrix determines a set of vectors up to an isometry. I'm trying to prove this statement.

More specifically, let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$. Here, I'm thinking of $A$ and $B$ as a stacking of $m$ row vectors, each row vector living in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Given that $AA^T = BB^T$, I want to show there exists an orthonormal matrix $P$ such that $||Pa_i|| = ||b_i||$ for $i=1,...,m$, where $a_i$ (resp. $b_i$) denotes the $i$-th row of $A$ (resp. $B$).

Here's what I've tried. Let $A = U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^T$ and $B = U_2 \Sigma_2 V_2^T$ be the SVDs of $A$ and $B$. Then, since $U_1$ is an orthonormal basis for $AA^T$ and likewise for $U_2$, there must exist a orthonormal matrix $P$ such that $U_2 = P U_1 = P U$. Furthermore, since $\sigma_i(A)^2 = \lambda_i(AA^T)$, $\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2 = \Sigma$. So since $A V_1 = U \Sigma$, plugging into $B$'s SVD we get $B = P A V_1 V_2^T$.

This is where I got stuck, as I don't know how to deal with the $V_1 V_2^T$ on the right. I believe $V_1$ and $V_2$ will be orthonormal basis for the same subspace, but I don't think it's true that they will be the *same* basis. I could also make the same argument for the $U_i$'s and say there is some orthonormal $Q$ which maps between $V_1$ and $V_2$, leaving something like $B = P A Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to show is that if $A$, $B$ are $m\times n$ then
$$A\cdot  A^T= B\cdot  B^T$$
if and only if there exists $U$ $m\times m$ matrix so that $U\cdot U^T = I_m$ and 
$B = A \cdot U$

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is easy but instructive:

$$B \cdot B^T = A U U^T A^T = A (U U^T) A^T = A \cdot I_m \cdot A^T = A \cdot A^T$$

Let's do $\Rightarrow$. We'll use your idea with SVD. Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A = U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^T \\
B = U_2 \Sigma_2 V_2^T 
\end{eqnarray*}
Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
AA^T = U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^T\cdot  V_1 \Sigma_1 U_1^T= U_1 \Sigma_1^2 U_1^T\\
BB^T = U_2 \Sigma_2 V_2^T\cdot V_2 \Sigma_2 U_2^T= U_2 \Sigma_2^2 U_2^T
\end{eqnarray*}
Let's recall the notion of a positive square root of a positive semidefinite matrix. Basically 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{AA^T} = U_1 \Sigma_1 U_1^T \\
\sqrt{BB^T} = U_2 \Sigma_2 U_2^T 
\end{eqnarray*}
We have $AA^T = BB^T$ so $\sqrt{AA^T}  = \sqrt{BB^T} $ or 
$$U_1 \Sigma_1 U_1^T = U_2 \Sigma_2 U_2^T $$
We are done now:
\begin{eqnarray*}
B = U_2 \Sigma_2 V_2^T= U_2 \Sigma_2 U_2^T \cdot U_2 V_2^T = U_1 \Sigma_1 U_1^T \cdot (U_2 V_2^T)  = \\
= U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^T \cdot (V_1 U_1^T) \cdot (U_2 V_2^T) = A \cdot U
\end{eqnarray*}

Really this is about the polar decomposition $A = \sqrt{A A^T} \cdot W_1$ and similar for $B$.

Comment: What about the case that we know that for any PSD matrix $ P $ we have the equality $ {A}^{T} P A = {B}^{T} P B $, can we say that $ A = \pm B $?

Comment: The proof assumes that the matrices are square, for example, by considering $\Sigma_1^2$, where $\Sigma$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. I don't see how to make the proof work in the nonsquare case.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other proofs do not address the case $n \neq m$, let me provide a proof that does not rely on SVD.

Let $u_1$, ...$u_m$ the rows of $A$ and $v_1$, ..., $v_m$ the rows of $B$ and $k$ the dimension of the span of $u_1$,..., $u_m$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that this span is generated by $u_1$, ..., $u_k$.

Choose an orthonormal basis $e_{k+1}, ..., e_m$ of the space orthogonal to $vect(u_1,..., u_k)$ and an orthonormal family $e'_{k+1}, ..., e'_m$ in the space orthogonal to $vect(v_1,..., v_k)$.
The linear map sending the $u_i$ to the $v_i$ and the $e_j$ to the $e'_j$ is the desired isometry.

For all $x \in E$, there exist $\lambda_i$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, such that
$ x = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i u_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \lambda_i e_i
$.

This implies
$ \phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i v_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \lambda_i e'_i.
$.

We know that $\langle u_i,e_j \rangle = 0$ and $\langle v_i, e'_j \rangle = 0$, so
$$
\|x\|^2 
= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i \lambda_j \langle u_i, u_j \rangle  + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \lambda_i^2
= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_i \lambda_j \langle v_i, v_j\rangle + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \lambda_i^2 
= \| \phi(x) \|^2.
$$
We are left to show that $\phi(u_j) = v_j$ for all $j > k$. We know that there exist $\lambda_i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$, such that
$$
u_j = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i u_i.
$$
Expanding the square of the norms gives
$$
  \Bigl\| u_j - \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i u_i \Bigr\|^2
= \Bigl\| v_j - \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \Bigr\|^2
$$
and we can conclude
$\displaystyle 
v_j = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i = 
\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \phi(u_i) = \phi(u_j).
$

Answer (score 0):

Start with full rank: if all nonsingular,
$$ I = A^{-1} A A^T (A^T)^{-1}  = A^{-1} B B^T (A^T)^{-1},  $$
$$ I = (A^{-1} B )  (A^{-1} B )^T  $$